# Mysql ORDER BY (Column2+Column3) if Column1 is empty?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table `CLIENTS` like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
| ID |  Name     |   Surname   |    Company    |
------------------------------------------------
|  1 |  John     |      Doe    |               |
------------------------------------------------
|  2 |           |             |     Company 1 |
------------------------------------------------
|  3 |   Mark    |   Blue      |     Company 2 |
------------------------------------------------
|  4 |           |             |     Company 3 |
------------------------------------------------
|  5 |     Jim   |   Yellow    |               |
```

Actually I've a script PHP that returns results `SELECT * FROM CLIENTS ORDER BY Company ASC`. To retrieve results alphabetically ASC ordered

The results are inserted (for view) in a table where column `NAME or COMPANY` is the `Company` (if compiled) or `Surname + Name` (if Name and Surname are compiled)

```
<?php
foreach ( $row as $res )
if ( $res['Company'] != "" ) { echo $res['Company']; } else { echo $res['Surname'] . " " . $res['Name']; }
?>
```

TABLE:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>NAME or COMPANY</th>
     <th>others info</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Doe John</td>
     <td> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Yellow Jim</td>
     <td> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Company 1</td>
     <td> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Company 2</td>
     <td> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Company 3</td>
     <td> </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

But my result are incorrect because of the 2 records with empty `Company` value

`Company` is not a required field: if `Company` is empty, then I need to compile `Name` and `Surname` fields.

In this case, I need to modify my script to return by a new dynamic column based on this check: if `Company` is compiled then `NEWCOLUMN = Company` else `NEWCOLUMN = Surname + " " + Name`
then

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTS ORDER BY NEWCOLUMN
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How do we know the relationship between a name with no company and a company with no name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to create the new column value:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN Company != '' THEN Company
            ELSE CONCAT(Surname, " ", Name) 
       END AS newcolumn
FROM clients
ORDER BY newcolumn
```

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the query like this :

```
SELECT if (company='', concat(Surname, " ", Name) , company) as NEWCOLUMN 
FROM clients ORDER BY NEWCOLUMN
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
order by company_name, surname, name
```

This also has the advantage that it can use an index.

If you want the column:

```
select coalesce(company_name, concat_ws(' ', surname, name)) as newname
```

This assumes that "empty" means `NULL`.